# problems with decodeURI with %^ characters

Tags: javascript, decode

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  var uri = "%^my test**.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
  document.write(decodeURI(uri));   
</script>
```

Error:

```
Line: 6
Error: The URI to be decoded is not a valid encoding
```

Is there anyway of decoding the combinations like %^ before calling the actual decodeURI?

Comment: are you sure you dont mean to "encode" rather than decode?

Comment: Why is that %^ in the URI anyway, and what do you want it to be decoded to?

Comment: Agreed, at least why is % there, because it is the escape character for encoding other URI entities.  Plus you have other non ASCII characters in the URI, which should be encoded, as it isn't safe to assume Unicode characters can be handled in URIs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not a valid URI. URIs aren't allowed to contain unencoded non-ASCII or reserved characters. You can't use literal `%`, it has to be encoded as `%25`.

```
 var uri="%25^my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab";
```

Comment: Sorry to dig up an old post, but what is the **= operator?

Comment: @J.Hendrix That's not an operator, SO's markdown formatting got messed up